# VMware: Reducing number of fullscreen monitors breaks VM

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm running a Lenovo P50 with Windows 10, VMware Player 12, and an Ubuntu 14.04 guest. I have 3 external monitors connected, for a total of 4 screens.

When I run VMware, I can go into fullscreen mode on 1, 2, 3, or 4 monitors. This works very well, and the Ubuntu guest updates automatically and correctly to have my monitors in the correct orientation.

However, when I reduce the number of monitors used by the VM, say from 2 monitors to 1, the following bad behaviors happen:

- The second monitor gets frozen with an image of what used to be on that monitor in the VM. I can't reclaim it without shutting down the VM.
- The VM remains mostly functional on the first monitor, but the X screen remains big enough for both monitors. The VMware window now has scrollbars that allow me to look to the right and see what's on the guests's second virtual monitor.

My laptop has an Nvidia Quadro M1000M. I'm running the latest Quadro driver from Nvidia's site (369.09-quadro-grid-desktop-notebook-win10-64bit-international-whql).

Any idea what's going on? This is preventing me from being able to dock/undock my laptop without hard-resetting my VM.

Comment: The host’s video driver should not be relevant here. The VM doesn’t see it, after all.

Comment: I agree, but the fact that the host monitor remains unusable indicates something might be wrong with the host system.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood that part. I thought the VM was misbehaving when it was in fact VMware Player.